# Git Commit - Unresponsive Terminal Mac OS Catalina

Tags: git, macos, terminal, commit

I am trying to do a git commit on the local machine through Terminal . I get a screen that is unresponsive. I get a message : " Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit." I press 'i', get 'Insert', press esc, then I press ':" then I type git commit -m"", and then I get an error. Help!

Comment: ?? Why dont you include the message in the git command rather than bringing up the vi? also! show the exact command you used.  also after typing : colon in vi type q then return.

Comment: Got it! Thank You

Comment: This is mostly a matter of learning to use the editor Git chose—in this case, apparently vi or vim—or, if you know some other editor, telling Git to *use* that other editor, rather than vi/vim. You can tell Git about your preferred editor, although depending on which editor you like, sometimes setting this up is a bit of a pain.